# Unable to click on link given in dropdown. Able to get link text and also link is highlighted when i do click();

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used `findElements` to get all elements in drop down.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*@id='flyout']/div[1]/ul/li"));
```

In a for loop, I am getting the name of the link. Now I want to click on the link. When I do `list.get(i).click();`, the corresponding element is highlighted but click is not happened. also no error was thrown.

I'm using Firefox.

Note: I have used `findElements` as drop down is not given in select value in HTML.

Comment: I would imagine the thing to click in *inside* the `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that the drop down has a "link". I think the list of elements that you are iterating through are just li elements, make sure there is an < a href .. > element within the li element. You need to click on the < a > and not < li >.

I hope this helps.

Also, if you already know which option in the list you want to click why are you storing the complete list and then iterating through it? Just find the link with the desired text and click it!

```
driver.findelement(by.linktext("link text")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your xpath does not really return the clickable element.

If dropdown items are links, then perhaps need to provide locator that leads to the hyperlink.